# How to check the length value of cell in datagrid view?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm able to validate the cells if they are empty but I'm not able to check the length of the cell. I want the user to enter 5 digits and if it is less than 5, show up a message box.

I tried `cellvalue.length` method but its not working.

```
Private Sub dgvResults_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvResults.CellValidating
        'variables
        Dim columnName As String = dgvResults.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
        Dim cellVal As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString()

        'Datagrid view validation
        If ((e.ColumnIndex = 0) And (e.FormattedValue = "") And (Not (cellVal.Length = 5))) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MessageBox.Show(columnName & " must be 5 Digits Long!")
        ElseIf (e.ColumnIndex = 1 And e.FormattedValue = "") Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MessageBox.Show(columnName & " cannot be blank!")
        ElseIf (e.ColumnIndex = 2 And e.FormattedValue = "") Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MessageBox.Show(columnName & " cannot be blank!")
        ElseIf ((e.ColumnIndex = 3) And (e.FormattedValue = "") And (Not IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue))) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MessageBox.Show(columnName & " cannot be blank!")
        ElseIf ((e.ColumnIndex = 4) And (Not IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue))) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MessageBox.Show(columnName & " cannot be blank!")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following causes your code to not work:

```
(e.FormattedValue = "") And (Not (cellVal.Length = 5))
```

You are checking if the value is empty **and also** it's length is <> 5.

But you want to ensure that `cellVal.Length` is = 5:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso cellVal.Length <> 5 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        MessageBox.Show(columnName & " must be 5 Digits Long!")
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need:

```
cellval.text.length
```